# PL/SQL error code PLS-00103

Tags: plsql, syntax-error

I wrote a PL/SQL script to output all the first name and last name of a customer but

I am getting an error

```
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
 . into bulk
```

[image: error]

Please advice. thanks

Comment: Sorry, but what is the point of second FETCH inside the loop? What do you aim to achieve with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `into CurrentPos` on line 12.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to use a for loop instead of open/fetch/close. Save you a lot of lines of code and is the recommended way to do it by Oracle.